# Why is my order of concat lists wrong?

Tags: list, f#, functional-programming, tail-recursion

I'm trying to make an example function tail recursive.
Here is the original function:

```
let rec s xs ys =
    match (xs, ys) with
    |([],[]) -> []
    |(xs, []) -> xs
    |([], ys) -> ys
    |(x::xs,y::ys) -> x::y::s xs ys
```

Below is my attempt to make it tail recursive:

```
let sC xs ys =
    let rec sCTR xs ys acc =
        match (xs, ys) with
        |([],[]) -> acc
        |(xs, []) -> acc@xs
        |([], ys) -> acc@ys
        |(x::xs,y::ys) -> sCTR xs ys acc@[x]@[y]

    sCTR xs ys []
```

My issue is, however, that the order of the items are all wrong. 
When I input the lists [1;2;3;] [7;8;] in the first function I get the result [1; 7; 2; 8; 3]
But when I input [1;2;3;] [7;8;] in the second function I get [3; 2; 8; 1; 7]

Why is the order wrong? I thought that list1@list2 would result in a new list with the order of list1 elements first and then list2 elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've just assumed the wrong precedence for `@`; what you've got is interpreted as

```
(sCTR xs ys acc)@[x]@[y]
```

but what you want is

```
sCTR xs ys (acc@[x]@[y])
```

Comment: Ahh I see. That makes sense - thanks a lot. I'll mark this as the correct answer once the timer runs out.

Comment: As a more general rule -- function application always has higher precedence than operators.